# Email do not render properly on Outlook PC?

Tags: html, css, mailchimp, mailing

Here is the code of my template. Everything looks fine in every clients except Outlook (PC) where it appears in full width and with bad CSS. It's ok on Outlook (Mac) and I don't understand what could be the issue here.

Most important part is the width issue.

https://codefile.io/f/m16xYHMFUY

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/128T3.jpg)

Comment: [Try an **inliner**](https://customer.io/blog/how-to-make-css-play-nice-in-html-emails-without-breaking-everything/#:~:text=1.,head%3E%20section%20to%20inline%20CSS.) 

Comment: https://www.caniemail.com/ Can be useful in checking what css is supported. Overall outlook does not score very highly.

Comment: Most important part is the width issue witch is actually already inline.

Comment: Please strip the code down to a small example. I notice there is quite a bit of use of position which is not fully supported in outlook, is that having an effect?

Comment: I tried to remove all position: absolute and relative, every width: 100% and applied width: 600px to body. Still the same.

Comment: Any idea on the way to make a simple container for Outlook? It's very strange that it don't recognize the max-width propriety.

Comment: To make a simple basic template for email, stick to the basics.- e.g. use table for layout and don't use any unsupported CSS properties. Please provide a template within your question which we can work on, and cut it right down from the complex one you have on that external site.